# Why isn't my Angular.js GET request working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arduino, arduino-yun

My goal is to spin a servo for a certain amount of seconds on a HTML button click. I am using an Arduino Yun as my microcontroller.

When I type in the URL directly the servo spins as it should. When I click on these buttons using the Angular.js GET request nothing happens. Even a regular form submit button works.

Is there something missing from my code?

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Here is my front-end code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>winner's cat Feeder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ArduinoCtrl" class="container">
        <button ng-click="setServo(1)" class="btn">3 Seconds(Food)</button>
        <button ng-click="setServo(2)" class="btn">9 Seconds(Food)</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function ArduinoCtrl($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.setServo = function (setting)
        {
            var url = "http://192.168.1.79/arduino/" + setting
            $http.get(url);
        }

    }

</script>
```

If I just type in the URL in my browser with the setting value of 1 or 2 the servo works fine.

Comment: Can You try it with - http with www

Comment: And  you can show us the error to help better

Comment: @Furkan Katman Thanks you for reply. No this does not work. Doesn't look like my code is reaching the get request. There is no error. The webpage just sits.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser, does it give an error message or it stays at pending? What server are you running?

Comment: @Billy Unterminated string constant (JavaScript). I am using this with VS2012, so IIS.

Comment: use javascript debugging and find the error then we can solve the problem , and it is probably a tiny mistake or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see working demo

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ArduinoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.response = {};
  $scope.progress = false;
  $scope.setServo = function(setting) {
    $scope.progress = true;
    var url = "http://192.168.1.79/arduino/" + setting
    $http.get(url).then(sucess, error).then(function() {
      $scope.progress = false;
    });

    function sucess(response) {

      angular.copy(response, $scope.response)


    }

    function error(response) {

      angular.copy(response, $scope.response)


    }
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ArduinoCtrl" class="container">
    <button ng-click="setServo(1)" class="btn">3 Seconds(Food)</button>
    <button ng-click="setServo(2)" class="btn">9 Seconds(Food)</button>

    <p ng-show="progress">Please wait</p>
    <div ng-hide="progress">
      <hr/>
      <p>Response</p>
      <pre>{{response | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ng-app` directive and add your controller to a module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>winner's cat Feeder</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ArduinoCtrl" class="container">
        <button ng-click="setServo(1)" class="btn">3 Seconds(Food)</button>
        <button ng-click="setServo(2)" class="btn">9 Seconds(Food)</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function ArduinoCtrl($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.setServo = function (setting)
        {
            var url = "http://192.168.1.79/arduino/" + setting
            $http.get(url);
        }

    }

    angular.module("myApp", []).controller("ArduinoCtrl", ArduinoCtrl);

</script>
```